# CodePush target versions and Testflight

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

So I have uploaded a code push earlier with the target version as ">=1.0.1" (Already out on the app store)

But now I have an updated version uploaded to Testflight version 1.0.2
so I went back into the App center code push console, and updated the previously released code push's target version to ">=1.0.1 <1.0.2"

But the old update is still being downloaded when I install version 1.0.2 from Testflight. So what I want to know is, does what I did make sense? Or is there a better process for uploading new version of the app

Answer (score 1):

The following table is pulled from this answer on SO:
[How to deploy CodePush bundle for multiple versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367684/how-to-deploy-codepush-bundle-for-multiple-versions)

```markdown
Range Expression    Who gets the update
----------------    ----------------------
1.2.3               Only devices running the specific binary app store version 1.2.3 of your app
*                   Any device configured to consume updates from your CodePush app
1.2.x               Devices running major version 1, minor version 2 and any patch version of your app
1.2.3 - 1.2.7       Devices running any binary version between 1.2.3 (inclusive) and 1.2.7 (inclusive)
>=1.2.3 <1.2.7      Devices running any binary version between 1.2.3 (inclusive) and 1.2.7 (exclusive)
1.2                 Equivalent to >=1.2.0 <1.3.0
~1.2.3              Equivalent to >=1.2.3 <1.3.0
^1.2.3              Equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0
```

So with ">=1.0.1 <1.0.2" it seems that you're asking for the update to affect all app versions 1.0.1 or below as well as all app versions up to *but not including* 1.0.2.